# HapiJS - MySQL: Query successful but postman returns Internal server error

Tags: mysql, node.js, hapi.js

I am trying to create an authentication system using Hapi and MySQL, I am testing it using postman, and I am also logging the output of the query on the terminal console.

The thing is, the console outputs the query successfully, however, postman returns `An internal server error occurred`, and the console doesn't return any error. I'll send the handler function of my route, found below:

```
    handler: async function(req, h) {

        const pass = req.payload.password;
        const username = req.payload.username;
        var res;
        res = await con.query("SELECT * FROM `Person` WHERE `Username` = ?", username,
            (err, rows, fields) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("Query Error: ", err, "!");
                    return err;
                } else {
                    console.log("Query Successful!");
                    const person = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows[0]));
                    console.log(person);
                    if(person != null) {
                        //const hashedPass = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(req.payload.password, person.salt, 10000, 64, 'sha1').toString('base64');
                        if(pass != person.Password) {
                            return boom.badRequest('Invalid username/password.');
                        } else {
                            var token = jwt.sign(person, config.jwtKey);
                            person.token = token;
                            return person;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return boom.badRequest('Invalid username/password. Failed.');
                    }            
                }
            }           
        );
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that `con.query` function return a promise object.

Comment: yes, I changed my code so that it returns a promise on success:
`...
person.token = token;
res = person;
return new Promise(() =>{
return res;
});
...`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding another node_module that encapsulates the regular `mysql` node module functions with promises.
The package is called `promise-mysql`.